# Code a Two Factor Authenticator for Windows in C++?

Tags: c++, windows, authentication, two-factor-authentication

It´s my goal to code a Two Factor Authentication for Windows.

It should work for Windows 10 but also for Windows 7. 
I want to know if it´s possible to code one in c++ or in any other programming language. So basically I just want to know if I can edit the Windows Login Window.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Too broad... Maybe start by reading about [LSA Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/secauthn/lsa-authentication) and authentication packages. You might also want to read about the SSO window and session.